# how to validate an arithmetic expression?

Tags: java

I have a program which ask user to input an arithmetic expression, how can I validate the expression.  For example: user input"1.2+3.4*(3.2+2.3)-12.1/3.4", it will output the same expression cause it is valid. If user input "/1.2", it will say invalid input, please enter the right expression.
 "* 1.2","1.2**3.4","1.2//3.4",and "1.2 + * 3.4" are all consider invalid.  However,"-3+4","3++4","3*+4",and"3+-6"are consider valid. 
Please help me.

Here is what I have so far.

```
private static boolean validate(String s) { 
    if (s.isEmpty()) { 
        return false;
    } else { 
      // remove all spaces 
      s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); 
      // remove all repeated char 
      // check if string contains only numbers and +-*/ 
      String ValidChars = "+-*/().1234567890"; 
      boolean result = true; 
      for (char c : s.toCharArray()) { 
          if (ValidChars.indexOf(c) == -1) { 
              result = false; 
          } 
      } 

      return result; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: A recursive descent parser will work nicely.

Comment: Write some code, even if it is wrong, and show the effort here. Without any effort on your part, no one's going to waste their time doing your homework.

Comment: @user3448414 his example contains valid characters, but incorrect syntax; he needs a grammar parser, such as a recursive descent or L parser.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still confusing.

Comment: I am a starter in java programming, can your guys tell me something simple to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Script Engine Manager class of `import javax.script.*` .

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

Now you have to evaluate your expression like this.

```
engine.eval(expression);//where expression is String in your case User Input
```

But Surround it with `try-catch` because if expression is not valid it will through `ScriptException`.

So if you get Exception means it's not valid expression.